# hide appended button in jquery using condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have created a website with quiz, where questions are loaded from database, one at a time. At the end of all questions, score is shown. There is a back button for the user to edit the question which i appended using ajax.

```js
<script>
  var currentQuestion = '';
  var preQuestion = 'false';
  function getPreQuestion(answer1=false, answer2=false, answer3=false, answer4=false){
      $.post("mohajax.php",
      {
        'previous_question' : 'Yes',
          next_id: currentQuestion,
          answer1: answer1,
          answer2: answer2,
          answer3: answer3,
          answer4: answer4,
      },
      function(data, status){
          $('#container_for_questions').html(data);
      });
  }
  function getQuestion(curr_id, answer1=false, answer2=false, answer3=false, answer4=false){
      if(curr_id != -1){
        currentQuestion = curr_id; // Set the value of curret question in global variable
        preQuestion = 'true'; }// Set previous question to true // Set previous question to true
      $.post("mohajax.php",
      {
          next_id: parseInt(curr_id)+1,
          answer1: answer1,
          answer2: answer2,
          answer3: answer3,
          answer4: answer4,
      },
      function(data, status){
          $('#container_for_questions').html(data);
          if(preQuestion == 'true'){
            $('#container_for_questions').append("<button onclick='getPreQuestion()'>Previous<button>");
          }
      });
  }

  function getCorrectAnswer(curr_id, answer1=false, answer2=false, answer3=false, answer4=false){
      $.post("mohajax_get_correct_answer.php",
      {
          next_id: parseInt(curr_id),
          answer1: answer1,
          answer2: answer2,
          answer3: answer3,
          answer4: answer4,
      },
      function(data, status){
          $('#container_for_questions').html(data);
      });
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
          $('body').on('click','input[type="radio"]', function(){
              var curr_id = $('.question').data('nextQuestion');
              var answer1 = $('#radio1').is(':checked');
              var answer2 = $('#radio2').is(':checked');
              var answer3 = $('#radio3').is(':checked');
              var answer4 = $('#radio4').is(':checked');
              getCorrectAnswer(curr_id, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4);
            setTimeout(
                getQuestion.bind(this,curr_id, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4), 1000);

      });
      getQuestion(-1);
  });

  </script>
```

below is my file using which i call my questions

```html
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","quiz"); // change here to your data
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Check the number of all questions, if next_id is more than last question, back to first or whatever you want;
$response=mysqli_query($con,"select * from moh limit 25");
$number_of_all_questions = mysqli_num_rows($response);

if($_POST['next_id'] == 0){
 // reset to default
 $_SESSION["correct_score"] = 0;
 $_SESSION["not_correct_score"] = 0;
}


if($number_of_all_questions <= $_POST['next_id']){
 // Quiz finished, show results

    echo"<div>
 <h2>Results:</h2>
 <p>Your score is: {$_SESSION['correct_score']} out of 25</p>
 

 </div>";



}else{

 // query next question
 $response=mysqli_query($con,"select * from moh WHERE id =(select min(id) from moh where id > {$_POST['next_id']})");
 ?>

 <?php while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($response,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>

  <div id="question_<?= $result['id'] ?>" class='question' data-next-question="<?= $_POST['next_id'] ?>"> <!--check the class for plurals if error occurs-->
   <h2><?= $result['id'].".".$result['question_name'] ?></h2>
      <div class='align'>
    <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1' name='1' <?= (isset($_POST['previous_question']) && $_SESSION["last_answer"] == '1') ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>>
    <label id='ans1' for='radio1'><?= $result['answer1'] ?></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio2' name='2' <?= (isset($_POST['previous_question']) && $_SESSION["last_answer"] == '2') ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>>
    <label id='ans2' for='radio2'><?= $result['answer2'] ?></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio3' name='3' <?= (isset($_POST['previous_question']) && $_SESSION["last_answer"] == '3') ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>>
    <label id='ans3' for='radio3'><?= $result['answer3'] ?></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio4' name='4' <?= (isset($_POST['previous_question']) && $_SESSION["last_answer"] == '4') ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>>
    <label id='ans4' for='radio4'><?= $result['answer4'] ?></label>
</div>
   <br/>
   <?php /*<input type="button" data-next-question="<?= $_POST['next_id'] ?>" id='next' value='Next!' name='question' class='butt'/> */?>
  </div>
 <?php }?>
<?php }?>
<?php mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

now the problem is , when all the questions are finished,the score is shown in the same page using ajax. but its shown with the back button which i appended to edit question. how can i hide it when all the questions are over and score is shown

Comment: When you echo your results can you add a `<script>` tag that uses jquery to `.hide()` your back button?

Comment: am new to coding. can you show me the code

Comment: What is the id of your back button?

Comment: i have appended it like .append("<button onclick='getPreQuestion()'>Previous<button>")

Comment: @MrGlass i have not given an id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this condition

```html
if ($number_of_all_questions <= $_POST['next_id']) {
    // Quiz finished, show results

    echo"<div>
    <h2>Results:</h2>
    <p>Your score is: {$_SESSION['correct_score']} out of 25</p>
    </div>";
} else {
```

just add this

```js
<script>
    $("button[onclick='getPreQuestion()']").hide();
</script>
```

**Final code**

```js
if($number_of_all_questions <= $_POST['next_id']){
    // Quiz finished, show results

    echo"<div>
    <h2>Results:</h2>
    <p>Your score is: {$_SESSION['correct_score']} out of 25</p>
    <script>
        $(\"button[onclick='getPreQuestion()']\").hide();
    </script>
    </div>";
} else {
```

Comment: its showing syntax error, unexpected 'button' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Oh, my bad, check the edit now

Comment: the problem is with the quotes. i changed it to single quotes for 'button[onlick=

Comment: its working. i also want to hide a div. how can i do that

Comment: @rifanriyaz What div?

Comment: i didnt see your reply so i posted a question :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907749/not-able-to-hide-div-using-condition-in-javascript