# Not able to hide div using condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have created a website with quiz, where questions are loaded from database, one at a time. At the end of all questions, score is shown. I have created a timer for like below:

```js
var tim;
var min = 25;
var sec = 01;
var f = new Date();

function f1() {
    f2();
    document.getElementById("starttime").innerHTML = "You Started Your Exam At " + f.getHours() + ":" + f.getMinutes();
}

function f2() {
    if (parseInt(sec) > 0) {
        sec = parseInt(sec) - 1;
        document.getElementById("showtime").innerHTML = "Time Left :<br>" + min + " Minutes ," + sec + " Seconds";
        tim = setTimeout("f2()", 1000);
    } else {
        if (parseInt(sec) == 0) {
            min = parseInt(min) - 1;
            if (parseInt(min) == 0) {
                clearTimeout(tim);
                location.href = "score.php";
            } else {
                sec = 60;
                document.getElementById("showtime").innerHTML = "Time Left :<br>" + min + " Minutes ," + sec + " Seconds";
                tim = setTimeout("f2()", 1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
setTimeout(function() {
    alert("5 minutes remaining");
}, 1200000);
```

```html
<div class="zara">
    <form align="center" id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table width="100%" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="col_third end">
                            <div class="hover panel">
                                <div class="front">
                                    <div class="box1">
                                        <p>
                                            <div id="showtime"></div>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="back">
                                    <div class="box2">
                                        <p>
                                            <div id="starttime"></div>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- <div id="starttime"></div><br /> -->
                        <div id="endtime"></div><br />
                        <!-- <div id="showtime"></div> -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The score is displayed in the same page using ajax and I have done the following script if all questions are over:

```html
if($number_of_all_questions <=$ _POST[ 'next_id']){ // Quiz finished, show results echo
  "<div>
   <h2>Results:</h2>
    <p>Your score is: {$_SESSION['correct_score']} out of 25</p>
      <script>
      $('button[onclick='getPreQuestion()']').hide();
    $('.zara').hide();
    </script>
  </div>";
}
```

Everything works fine but the timer div is not hidden. I want to hide the timer div when the score is shown/ when all questions are over.

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: no error is shown

Comment: You should get the error in console. You have wrong syntax in line $('button[onclick='getPreQuestion()']').hide(); It should be $('button[onclick="getPreQuestion()"]').hide();

Comment: @Sabik that line is working fine. but the div "zara " is not hiding

Comment: If that last piece of code is coming from an ajax-call, it will never run.

Comment: $('.zara').hide(); this code is not working. this is comming from an ajax call

Comment: @Michel then how can i hide it

Comment: @proofzy i didnt understand. which page

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your javascript is being executed after jQuery is being included.

Try this way:

```
<?php
    if($number_of_all_questions <= $_POST[ 'next_id']){ // Quiz finished, show results 
    echo "<div>
        <h2>Results:</h2>
        <p>Your score is: {$_SESSION['correct_score']} out of 25</p>
        </div>"; 
    $finished = 1;
    }
?>


    <script>
    // let's store it from php variable to javascript
    var finished = "<?php echo $finished; ?>";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(finished === 1) {
           $('.zara').hide();
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '_POST' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file in

Comment: Het is getting this as a response from an ajax-call, so unless he is using `eval()` it will never run.

Comment: this has still error. the code is not propely formatted

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file in

Answer (score 0):

Your script will never run when you get it as a response from an ajax-call, unless you use some evil `eval()`.

Make a function called `hide()` and load it with your normal javascript:

```
function hide{
   $('button[onclick='getPreQuestion()']').hide();
   $('.zara').hide();
}
```

In your PHP only echo the div:

```
<?php
if($number_of_all_questions <=$ _POST[ 'next_id']){
 echo "<div>
    <h2>Results:</h2>
    <p>Your score is: {$_SESSION['correct_score']} out of 25</p>
    </div>";
 }
```

and in your ajax-code look for a clue the game has ended. Something like (I don't know much abouth jQuery, so there could be errors in here):

```
$.ajax({
  ....,
  success: function(result){
        //search for the word 'Results:'. This will return -1 if not found
        var n = result.search("Results:");
        //If the word is found, run function hide() 
        if(n>=0)hide();
       },
  ....
});
```

Answer (score -2):

For goodness sake, learn to simplify questions to only the matter at hand, don't just dump your entire code. Would have made it so much easier and faster for us to answer!

Just change the submit button to your form submission or whatever. I'm not going to sort through all that code myself (sorry). This should serve as a working template

```js
 var inv = document.getElementById('invisiblediv');
 var submitb = document.querySelector('button');
 
 submitb.addEventListener('click',function(){
  alert('Submitted form in time!');
  inv.style.visibility = 'visible';
  clearTimeout(testtimer);
 });
 
 var testtimer = setTimeout(function(){
    alert('Time limit expired, showing results!');
    inv.style.visibility = 'visible';
 }, 8000);
```

```css
#invisiblediv {
  visibility: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="invisiblediv">Hello world!</div>
<button>Show hidden results</button>
```

Comment: this is not the answer i want